# Redux time travel debugging with current time dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In my application I have a selector that checks if the data it's fetching is stale. If it isn't stale, the selector returns the data; else it doesn't. It checks the staleness by comparing the current time (via `new Date()`) with the time that the data was loaded.

When trying to scrub back in forth in actions in the Redux dev tools, however, since the time is not part of the Redux store, the selector will call the data stale even if at the time of the action it wasn't.

So the core problem seems to be that Redux is no longer acting as a single source of truth—the clock time is now an external dependency. The goal, then, would be for the clock time when the selector is accessed to be a part of the Redux state, to properly allow for time travel debugging.

But what is the most elegant way to have an *access* of the Redux store dispatch a state transition? One way is to manually add an `updateTime()` dispatch every time you access the selector, but that requires remembering every time the selector is invoked to make that call, which I find to be less than ideal.

Another floated option was to keep track of the current time upon every state transition, but that doesn't help since it doesn't actually trigger an update upon time of access, but only upon the time that the state itself changed.

How do other people deal with this problem? I'm failing to find a nice solution around this. Thanks!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could reproduce your problem in your question with a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: Is it not complicated to make a snippet that also loads the Redux dev tools? Otherwise time travel debugging isn't really a thing. Seems like a pain, I think the description is pretty clear and would be happy to clarify; I can make a quick Github repo that suffers from this though.

Comment: That's a reasonable objection, but the question isn't really about Redux Dev Tools is it? It's about the best way to change an external dependency (the time at which an action occurs) into an internal one. Which, by the way, is a great question and you've expressed it well; it's just much easier (for lazy folks like me anyway) to work out a solution if one can click on "Copy snippet to answer."

Comment: Sure, I'll write up a snippet then that experiences the problem but to see the failure in action you'd probably have to run it locally. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: (though it kind of is because this isn't really a problem if you're not trying to undo previously applied actions - not sure the context you'd do that in aside from using the Dev tools, though perhaps in the more general sense that's the case :))